# launchctl bootout on macOS Sonoma is failing with EIO = "Input/output error"

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma, launchctl

My macOS app stopped working on macOS 14.4.1 (Kernel: Darwin v.23.4.0), or "Sonoma". I started looking into it, and it turns out that when I try to remove my launch agent:

```
/bin/launchctl bootout gui/501 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.company.name.plist
```

`launchctl` fails for `bootout` with error code 5, or `EIO` = "Input/output error"

Is it something new to Sonoma, or what is the issue there?
It used to work on previous versions of macOS.

Note that the Mach-O executable for the launch agent is properly signed and notarized with the Apple portal.

The `.plist` in question goes as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.company.name.launch.agent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>LoginWindow</string>
        <string>Aqua</string>
    </array>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.company.name</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.company/name</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-a</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to unload first :

```
/bin/launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.company.name.plist
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering, is it something that they introduced in Sonoma, or was I doing it wrong before?

Comment: This should be introduced before Sonoma.